# $\mathcal{F}\subset \mathcal{E}$, Countable Union, $\mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{E})$

Tags: measure-theory

**$X\not= \emptyset, \mathcal{F}\subset \mathcal{E}\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$. If every Element $B \in \mathcal{E}$ can be written as a countable Union of Elements of $\mathcal{F}$, then prove that, $$\mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{E}).$$**

I know why this holds (it isn't very difficult to prove), but I have problems to write this down in a formal proof.

My suggestions:

"$\subset$":

$\mathcal{F}\subset \mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{E})$, so $\mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{F})\subset \mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{E})$

"$\supset$":

$\mathcal{E} \subseteq\mathcal{F} \cup \underbrace{\{A_1,A_2,... \in \mathcal{F}, \underbrace{\bigcup_i A_i}_{B} \in \mathcal{E}\}}_{\mathcal{F'}}$

Since the $\mathcal{A}_\sigma$ is closed under Union it follows that:
$\mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq \mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{A}_\sigma(\mathcal{F}\cup\mathcal{F}')$

What is here the right way to prove this (or is this enough)?

Comment: It's not very clear how you define $\mathcal{F}'$. It's the set of countable unions of elements of  $\mathcal{F}$ such that those unions are in  $\mathcal{E}$? Then  $\mathcal{F}'$ is equal to  $\mathcal{E}$. If  $\mathcal{F}'$ is something like the set of elements of  $\mathcal{F}$ such that their countable union is in  $\mathcal{E}$, then  $\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{F}'$ is equal to  $\mathcal{F}$. Maybe you should just define it as all possible countable unions of elements of  $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: This was my question, at the moment i don't know how. But your argument below is probably enough

Comment: Yes my arguments is definitely enough. But back to your way, I already suggested defining $\mathcal{F}'$ as the set of all possible unions of elements of $\mathcal{F}$. Doesn't this work?

Comment: I think $\mathcal{F}\cup\{\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} A: \mathcal{F}\in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{E}) \}$ is the right notation, this was my problem

Comment: that's not correct. check it again

Comment: Then i don't know. Whats the right definition?

Answer (score 1):

Since every $B\in \mathcal{E}$ is written as a countable union of elements ot $\mathcal{F}$, then $B$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{F})$. Hence,  $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{F})$, which suggests that $\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{E})\subset \mathcal{A}_{\sigma}(\mathcal{F})$.